# Box2d - how to create simple slowing down after drag and drp object? (Actionscript 3)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, box2d

So what I nedd is simple - how to create a drag and dropable circle with flex 4 and AS3 and using Box2d make it fly some more in the direction of drag and than stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LinearDamping`.

This is how I used it in my top down shooter to slow the object down if linear velocity stopped being applied.

```
//Body is created using body definition
var b:b2Body = GameCore.environment.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);

//Fixture definition holds data such as density, friction and shape
var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef;
fixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();

//Define vertices etc in polygon shape
var shape:b2CircleShape;
shape = new b2CircleShape(Values.ptm(_diameter / 2));

//Assign values
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = 1.5;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.3;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.45;

//Add fixture to appropriate body
b.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);    

//Movement Physics Settings
b.SetLinearDamping(_linearDamping);
b.SetAngularDamping(_angularDamping);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to make sure gravity is turned off (zero in both dimensions) i.e. something like

```
var gravity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2 (0.0, 0.0);
```

and then let friction slow the thing down.